# Show that a and b cannot have the same parity and that c is odd

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, pythagorean-triples

The theorem for the question is as follows:

The positive integers $(a, b, c)$ are a primitive Pythagorean triple with an odd if and only if
$a = m^2 - n^2$, $b = 2mn$, and $c = m^2 + n^2$
, where $m, n$ are relatively prime positive integers, not both odd, and $m > n$.

To show that a and b cannot be both odd or both even, do I need to show that either $m^2 - n^2$ or $2mn$ is odd and then show that the other must be even? How would I begin to show that one or the other is odd or even?

Comment: $2mn$ cannot be odd

Comment: If $a$ and $b$ are both even, the triple isn’t primitive.  If $a$ and $b$ are both odd, the sum of their squares leaves remainder $2$ when divided by $4$, so isn’t a square. So $a$ and $b$ are of opposite parity, so $a^2$ and $b^2$ are, so $c^2$ is odd, so $c$ is

Answer (score 1):

Side-A is always odd, if primitve, and can be any odd number greater than one so $m$ and $n$ must be of opposite parity or $m^2-n^2$ would be even.

Side-B is always even, because $B=2mn$, and is a multiple of four unless $(m,n)$ are  both odd and therefore non-primitve such as $F(3,1)=(8,6,10)$.

Side-C must be odd because it's square is the sum of an odd square and an even square.

If $(m,n)$ have a common factor $(f)$, then $GCD(A,B,C)>1$. For example
\begin{equation}
(m,n)=(fq,fs)\\
\implies A=f^2q^2-f^2s^2=f^2(q^2-s^2)\\
\qquad B=2fqfs=f^2(2qs)\\
\qquad C=f^2q^2+f^2s^2=f^2(q^2+s^2)
\end{equation}
Above, we can see that if $(m,n)$ are not mutually prime, then $GCD(A,B,C)=f^2$.